# SMF moderators can change their post count

Tags: forum

I have an SMF forum currently running on SMF 2.0RC4 and the moderators can change their post count. This is not a big problem as it's only available for the mods, but still I would like to know where I can change this. I found some settings in permissions settings, but when disabled, they could not change anything in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack your way out of it.

In ./Sources/Profile-Modify.php on line 568

```
'posts' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => $txt['profile_posts'],
        'log_change' => true,
        'size' => 7,
        'permission' => 'moderate_forum'
```

Change 'permission' => 'moderate_forum' to 'permission' => 'admin_forum'.
Then only admins can edit the post count.